# Move around form by dragging other element?

Tags: vb.net

I made a small program in VB.NET that injects Dlls into processes. This will help me learn how reverse engineering and form design. The only issue is I made the form a borderless form meaning I cant drag it. So what I did was added a GroupBox element that covers the form size. I want to be able to click and drag the GroupBox and move the whole form as if it was the form itself and wasn't borderless. This may sound confusing but here is my code so far.

```
    Private Sub Loader_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DLLs.Name = "DLLs"
        Button1.Text = "Browse"
        Label1.Text = "Waiting for process.exe"
        Timer1.Interval = 50
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL (*.dll) |*.dll"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For i As Integer = (DLLs.SelectedItems.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            DLLs.Items.Remove(DLLs.SelectedItems(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If IO.File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
            Dim TargetProcess As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(Textbox1.Text)
            If TargetProcess.Length = 0 Then

                Me.Label1.Text = ("Waiting for process.exe")
            Else
                Timer1.Stop()
                Me.Label1.Text = "Successfully injected"
                Call Inject()
            End If
        Else
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If IO.File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
            Dim TargetProcess As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(Textbox1.Text)
            If TargetProcess.Length = 0 Then
                Me.Label1.Text = ("Waiting for process.exe")
            Else
                Timer1.Stop()
                Me.Label1.Text = "Successfully injected"
                Call Inject()
            End If
        Else
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim FileName As String
        FileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\"))
        Dim DllFileName As String = FileName.Replace("\", "")
        Me.DLLs.Items.Add(DllFileName)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DLLs_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DLLs.SelectedIndexChanged
        Me.TopMost = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your groupbox is 'GroupBox1':

```
Private Sub GroupBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.MouseDown
    GroupBox1.Capture = False
    Dim msg As Message = Message.Create(Me.Handle, &HA1, 2, 0&)
    Me.DefWndProc(msg)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do consider testing this with Option Strict On in effect.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes of course, good comment. I grabbed this from a couple of older projects I had. The IDE suggestions with strict ON, work fine, which would be: Dim msg As Message = Message.Create(Me.Handle, &HA1, CType(2, IntPtr), CType(0&, IntPtr)) Sorry, not sure how to format code in comments.

Comment: Just put it where it belongs, in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code I use to handle similar situations. If you want to click anywhere on the form to drag you will have to create 'MouseDown' and 'MouseMove' Handlers for each control on the form.

```
Private m_CursorOffset As Point

Public Sub GroupBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        m_CursorOffset = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub GroupBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        'Distance we moved
        Dim d As Point = New Point(e.X - m_CursorOffset.X, e.Y - m_CursorOffset.Y)
        'New location of the form
        Dim adjustedLocation As New Point(Me.Location.X + d.X, Me.Location.Y + d.Y)

        ' Set the new position of our form
        Me.Location = adjustedLocation
    End If
End Sub
```